# Not able to ssh into RPI Zero W with raspbian Lite?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-zero

I have for weeks now tried to ssh into my RPI zero, and I cannot figure out what is wrong here. I've been using this guide https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb.

The installation finished without problems but every time i ssh into the RasPi, nothing happens. It just stalls.

What might i be doing wrong?

Comment: On the tutorial you have linked, there are seven steps to setup. Please tell us what step fails.

Comment: None of the steps fails... All goes well, until i Ssh to the pi..  It just stalls... nothing happens. It doesn't say that it cannot find the pi either?

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the exact `ssh` command you are using.

Comment: If it just stalls it sounds like the raspberry.local domain isn't resolving. Are you using a Windows or OS X host? If you're using Windows, I think you'll need to install something from Apple to enable it. See https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux/overview for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the BOOT partition there is a file called ssh. Just "`ssh`", not "`ssh.txt`".
Make sure the pi is finished booting before you ssh too.
If you are using windows, download [this](https://download.info.apple.com/Mac_OS_X/061-8098.20100603.gthyu/BonjourPSSetup.exe) and run the setup wizard first. It is called "print services" but it lets your computer recognize other computers, which windows has a problem with.